# Springboot using cert not working, gives Alias name does not identify a key entry

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, tomcat, https, pkcs#12

I am attempting to enable a certificate that was ordered on sslcertificaten.nl in my Spring Boot runnable JAR application with Tomcat 9. Here is what I'm doing:

```
keytool -import -alias springboot -file <name>.crt -keystore <application_name>.p12 -storetype PKCS12 -storepass <password>
```

In my Spring Boot `application.properties` file, I have the following:

```
server.ssl.key-store=<domain_name>.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=<password>
server.ssl.key-store-type=pkcs12
server.ssl.key-alias=springboot
server.port=8282
```

This is the error I am receiving:

```
Alias name [springboot] does not identify a key entry
```

Before, I used https://www.thomasvitale.com/https-spring-boot-ssl-certificate/ and on step 1a they use a self-signed SSL certificate, but I want to use a certificate that does not expire so quickly.

Can someone help me? Did I forget something?